# Uploading data values to google sheets without service account? PYTHON

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

I have been using this link to **read** spreadsheets in Python, which works perfectly well:
https://predictivehacks.com/the-easiest-way-to-connect-python-with-google-sheets/

However, I noticed there isn't any implementation for it to **write** and push datavalues into a spreadsheet on google. I did some research on google and noticed that the alternative ways seem to be to use a service account and share the spreadsheet to the service account email so that it can access it.

Note: I have the ID of the specific spreadsheet that I want to access

Questions:

- I'm working with this issue and sharing it to a google service account email doesn't seem to be an option for me. I was wondering if anyone know a way where I can work around this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **gspread** library. You can use OAuth Client ID to authenticate your application in gspread.

> 1. Enable API Access for a Project if you haven’t done it yet.
> 2. Go to “APIs & Services > OAuth Consent Screen.” Click the button for “Configure Consent Screen” and follow the directions to give your
>    app a name; you don’t need to fill out anything else on that screen.
>    Click Save.
> 3. Go to “APIs & Services > Credentials”
> 4. Click “+ Create credentials” at the top, then select “OAuth client ID”.
> 5. Select “Desktop app”, name the credentials and click “Create”. Click “Ok” in the “OAuth client created” popup.
> 6. Download the credentials by clicking the Download JSON button in “OAuth 2.0 Client IDs” section.
> 7. Move the downloaded file to ~/.config/gspread/credentials.json. Windows users should put this file to
>    %APPDATA%\gspread\credentials.json.

**For updating cells or range you can use gspread's update method:**

Example:

```
worksheet.update('A1:B2', [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

### References:

- [gspread Authentication](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-end-users-using-oauth-client-id)
- [gspread update()](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#updating-cells)
- [gspread Example Usage](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following but after authenticating, I am getting this error. ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

Comment: Kindly include code snippet and stack trace in your post above

Comment: Actually, I forgot to refresh my kernel  back then. Now everything works perfectly. And also, when the popup asks me to confirm the authentication, is this a one-time thing?

Comment: @mathgeek - Yes that is a one time thing.

Comment: Great awesome, thank you for your help! Appreciate it and upvoted :)